# how to make the legend smaller?

Tags: r

I am trying to make the legend smaller. Why does the "upperleft" make the legend so big?Here are my codes. Thank you!

```
dnsm <- density(ecls$MATH5[ecls$GENDER_fac == "male"])
plot(dnsf, 
     col = "red", 
     xlab = "Fifth Grade Math Score",
     main = "",
     las = TRUE,
     lwd = 2)
points(dnsm, col = "green", type = "l", lwd = 2)
legend(x = "topleft", 
       col = c("red", "green"),
       legend = c("female", "male"),
       lwd = 2)
```

Comment: You do not provide any data so we cannot see exactly what you see, but in my test, the legend was not especially big. If you want smaller text,  try adding `cex=0.8` to your legend statement.

Comment: the legend location, whether you use {x, y} or a keyword like "topleft", doesn't affect the size--it says where to put the upper left corner of the box

Comment: There's no data here for a [MCVE].